# Entity Framework migration with specific target platform

Tags: c#, .net-core, build, entity-framework-core

I am trying Windows WPF based on .NET Core 3, Entity Framework Core.

As one of my package does not support the target platform of AnyCPU. I have changed the target to x64. Building the solution is completed successfully in VS2019.

But when I add some new properties into the Data Context in EF. I have to add new migration to update the database design. But the command

```
dotnet ef migrations add
```

ended up with a "build failed". The error was the platform issue, the package replied with the issue of AnyCPU target.

Is there any way to let the building process initiated by the `dotnet ef migrations` command, use the x64 platform?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio 2019 (2017), you can go the project properties, and try change platform as in this picture to x64 and hen try running migrations command

[image]

Comment: I have done this. It works fine when I build the solution in VS2019. The problem occurs only when I run "dotnet ef migrations add".

Comment: which one is your project selected when you run it ? if you have multiple projects in your solution, you should do it for the project where your DB context and configurations are.